# Why do some websites make us wait before redirection?

Tags: web, wait

While browsing I found many websites say:

```
wait for 5 seconds and download will begin; or click this link to download now

or 

Wait for 5 seconds, we will redirect to specific website; if you are on fire click this link
```

Why do websites make us wait for 5 seconds? Are they doing something in that time?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes developer do not execute all code in same request they put their request in queue (exp. Rabbit MQ) so that another servers can handle it. It increase system performance. it takes some time when queue has much packets but it is so fast 5 secs are more enough to handle it. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

> Generally there are two reasons (from my experience):
>
> 1. You got to the page via a link and that page either doesn't exist anymore, or was moved. If it doesn't exist anymore, you will sometimes get redirected higher in the navigation stack (Apple does this with their documentation, sending users to a ore filled search of related/similar pages, if you're lucky). If it has been moved due to a change in the IA of the site, it may be in a "sun setting" period wherein the user is moved from the old URL to the new - to slowdown and stop further propagation of the old link. After the sun setting period that redirect page will be dropped for either a 404 page; or, the higher level search concept.
> 2. Depending on the type of form you are filling out, there may be a process which must be run without user interaction; however, these rarely have the option to click the link.
>
> Of course, with the latter part of the first reason, there must also be a process in place to stop this sort of thing and take the page down altogether. Either a date or a "when less than X users land on this page in a month, we can take it down" - so, sometimes a well intentioned change management consideration may never get fully resolved to the new way of things.
>
> Hope that helps.

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37731/why-do-websites-use-you-are-being-redirected-pages